# ffmpeg Image generation output results

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG to generate images from a video. I'd like to know the output names when the images are generated as a stream so I can upload them to s3 as they are generated.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf scale=800:-1 -vsync 0 output/thumbnail-%06d.png
```

The standard out is a bunch of video information but I'd like to know the generated file names if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced this isn't an XY problem, but you can do this by increasing the `-loglevel`:

```
$ ffmpeg -loglevel debug -i video.mp4 -vf scale=800:-1 -vsync 0 output/thumbnail-%06d.png
[…]
[image2 @ 0x55f0164248c0] Opening 'output/thumbnail-000001.png' for writing
[file @ 0x55f0166c9f80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x55f0166450c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 1 writeouts
[rawvideo @ 0x55f016424440] PACKET SIZE: 230400, STRIDE: 960
[image2 @ 0x55f0164248c0] Opening 'output/thumbnail-000002.png' for writing
[file @ 0x55f0166ca680] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x55f0166c9c80] Statistics: 0 seeks, 1 writeouts
[rawvideo @ 0x55f016424440] PACKET SIZE: 230400, STRIDE: 960
[image2 @ 0x55f0164248c0] Opening 'output/thumbnail-000003.png' for writing
[file @ 0x55f0166cb000] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x55f0166cb100] Statistics: 0 seeks, 1 writeouts
```

Optionally process with `awk` or similar:

```
$ ffmpeg -loglevel debug -i video.mp4 -vf scale=800:-1 -vsync 0 output/thumbnail-%06d.png |& awk -F' ' '/Opening/ { print $5 }'
output/thumbnail-%06d.png.
'output/thumbnail-000001.png'
'output/thumbnail-000002.png'
'output/thumbnail-000003.png'
```

That's a poor, lazy `awk` example but it will give you an idea at least. Might be worth adding `tee` so you can also get the full stderr output.